# How to resolve merge conflicts when merging two branches?

Tags: git

I have a branch A, and another branch B, which is created by someone. how to merge branch B to A without having any merge conflicts

Comment: There is a pretty good guide from git https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Comment: The easiest one is to merge branch A into B (and resolve conflicts) then merging branch B to A is painless.

Comment: To not have a merge conflict, you have to restrict yourself to make only changes on the branches that do not conflict. Otherwise, when there's a conflict, there's a conflict, and you have to resolve it; there's no way around it.

Answer (score 1):

Like others suggested you should check out [basic information on branching and merging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging).

Merge Conflicts are not bad. You probably just do not currently know how to resolve them. There is no way around them. A conflict is caused by your work, not by git. Git just helps you resolve those conflicts by finding them and displaying them to you.

Git also does much work during a merge for you automatically, but it does not have all the context of your work. It works on text and lines. It is not a general AI and does not posess any magic abilities to have any higher grasp.
It is optimized for code, yes, but it does not understand its purpose. At some point, sometimes, you have to do what it cannot possibly do.

Conflicts happen if 2 branches want to provide updates on the same lines. Both developers had a purpose with their changes that are aimed to come through intact. In resolving a conflict, possibly even with both developers at the same time involved, you see that they do.